# Make radar move dynamically with car movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am making a 2d game, and it contains a radar, and a vehicle (think GTA1 or GTA2). I want the radar to move accordingly to the cars rotation(i.e. Car is driving north, when car turns right, radar will also rotate accordingly). I am seem to have got it to work to an extent (the radar moves when the vehicle moves) but not so much in the right direction, and it gets to the point that the radar just continues to spin as soon as it has turned. Scripts I currently have is as follows:

Car Location Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class CarLocation : MonoBehaviour {

    public static float XAxis;
    public static float YAxis;
    public static float ZAxis;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        XAxis = transform.rotation.x;
        YAxis = transform.rotation.y;
        ZAxis = transform.rotation.z;
    }
}
```

Radar Rotation

```
  using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;



public class RotateRadar : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
          transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * (CarLocation.YAxis));
          print(Vector3.forward * (CarLocation.YAxis));
    }
}
```

Just thinking how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Are you using second camare for radar ?

Comment: Yes I have a second camera with a GUI layer which renders the radar

Comment: If you add that camera as child of player (or object) you want to track. Camera will copy rotation and transform from camera without the code.

Comment: Have unfortunately tried this and it only ends up in 2 ways. 1) Because the game isnt entirely 2d (2.5d more like), the radar ends up warping into the direction of the X Axis. When turning, rather than the radar it self moving, it actually ends up moving its entire position rather than rotating, hence needing a more dynamic code.

Comment: Couple of things.  1, `transform.rotation` returns a `Quaternion`, not euler angles.  `transform.Rotate()` expects euler angles but you're feeding it quaternion values.  2.  `Vector3.forward * (CarLocation.YAxis)` is equivalent to `(0,0,1) * YAxis = (0,0,YAxis)`  Without knowing what your up axis is it's hard to know if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jerdak, I have resolved the issue. I have changes the transform.Rotate() to transfer.eurlerAngles and multiplying the value from the YAxis by 100 to give a larger figure in order for the compass to actually move, which has done the trick :)